# Como salvar um base64 em um banco mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, upload

Estou criando uma aplicação usando AngularJS e usando webservlets com conexão no banco mysql.

Para gerar o binário, utilizo o seguinte código:

```
 $scope.adicionarArquivo = function (element) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.itemSelecionado.arquivo = reader.result;
    }, 1000);

};
```

O binário é gerado corretamente e consigo exibir a imagem em um tag IMG. O problema ocorre quando vou salvar no banco. Primeiro como devo armazenar esse binário no java para passar no mysql? E, qual variável crio no banco, blob? binary?

Comment: Você está usando algum framework no seu back-end, como Spring, ou é JDBC puro mesmo? A coluna no banco deve ser BLOB mesmo.

Comment: seria JDBC puro mesmo, eu mudei a coluna para longblob. Eu consegui resolver setando direto no longblob, seria a melhor forma?

Comment: BLOB = 64KB, MEDIUMBLOB = 16MB e LONGBLOB = 4GB... Cuidado ao utilizar longblob